# Comparing properties of the same object and different objects

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've created a multiple choice test for an rpg website.

The test has 14 questions.

Half of these questions and answers add numerical value inside 1 of 8 properties of an object called primaryResults.

The second half does exactly the same, but stores the data in an object called secondaryResults.

Now I need a way to compare all the properties of both of these objects in order to append the proper results to the user.

For example

If PrimaryResults.def > than the rest of the properties in primary.

and

If secondaryResults.def > than the rest of the properties of secondary.

Then append The div that corresponds to def/def to display.

Is there a more efficient way than

If primaryResults.def > primaryResults.ber && PrimaryResults.mnk && primaryResults.rng

Etc etc 
Edit: Code Added

```
$(".intro").appendTo('#display_box');
var question = $(".question");
var questionPosition = -1;
var results =$(".results");

var secondaryResults = {
    def:0,
    ber:0,
    mnk:0,
    rng:0,
    cle:0,
    thf:0,
    mge:0,
    dru:0,
};

var primaryResults = {
    def:0,
    ber:0,
    mnk:0,
    rng:0,
    cle:0,
    thf:0,
    mge:0,
    dru:0,
};



function clearBox(){
    $("#display_box").children().fadeOut(500).appendTo('#question_holding');
};



function cycle(){

    question.eq(questionPosition).fadeIn(500).appendTo("#display_box");
    $("#display_box").animate({scrollTop:0}, 500);


}





    $('#leftarrow').on('click', function(){
    questionPosition--;
    if (questionPosition <= -1) {questionPosition = 13};
    clearBox();
    cycle();





});





$('#rightarrow').on('click', function(){
    questionPosition++;
    if (questionPosition > 13) { questionPosition = 0};
    clearBox();
    cycle();

    if($('input[name^="answer"]:checked').length > 13 ) {
        $("#submit").css('display', 'block');
    }




});

$('#submit').on('click', function() {
$('input[name^= "answer"]:checked').each(function(){
        if ($(this).val() == "monkL"){
            secondaryResults.mnk += 1.02;

        }

        if ($(this).val() == "berserkerL"){
            secondaryResults.ber += .99;

        }

        if ($(this).val() == "defenderL"){
            secondaryResults.def += 1.01;

        }

        if ($(this).val() == "thiefL"){
            secondaryResults.thf += 1;

        }

        if ($(this).val() == "mageL"){
            secondaryResults.mge += .98;

        }

        if ($(this).val() == "clericL"){
            secondaryResults.cle += 1.03;

        }

        if ($(this).val() == "rangeL"){
            secondaryResults.rng += .97;

        }

        if ($(this).val() == "druidL"){
            secondaryResults.dru += 1.05;

        }



        })



    });


$('#submit').on('click', function() {
$('input[name^= "answer"]:checked').each(function(){
        if ($(this).val() == "monkM"){
            secondaryResults.mnk += 1.31;

        }

        if ($(this).val() == "berserkerM"){
            secondaryResults.ber += 1.29;

        }

        if ($(this).val() == "defenderM"){
            secondaryResults.def += 1.3;

        }

        if ($(this).val() == "thiefM"){
            secondaryResults.thf += 1.28;

        }

        if ($(this).val() == "mageM"){
            secondaryResults.mge += 1.27;

        }

        if ($(this).val() == "cleric"){
            secondaryResults.cle += 1.32;

        }

        if ($(this).val() == "rangeM"){
            secondaryResults.rng += 1.33;

        }

        if ($(this).val() == "druidM"){
            secondaryResults.dru += 1.26;

        }



        })



    });

$('#submit').on('click', function() {
$('input[name^= "answer"]:checked').each(function(){
        if ($(this).val() == "monkH"){
            secondaryResults.mnk += 1.5;

        }

        if ($(this).val() == "berserkerH"){
            secondaryResults.ber += 1.51;

        }

        if ($(this).val() == "defenderH"){
            secondaryResults.def += 1.52 ;

        }

        if ($(this).val() == "thiefH"){
            secondaryResults.thf += 1.49;

        }

        if ($(this).val() == "mageH"){
            secondaryResults.mge += 1.48;

        }

        if ($(this).val() == "clericH"){
            secondaryResults.cle += 1.47;

        }

        if ($(this).val() == "rangeH"){
            secondaryResults.rng += 1.53;

        }

        if ($(this).val() == "druidH"){
            secondaryResults.dru += 1.51;

        }



        })



    });

$('#submit').on('click', function() {
$('input[name^= "answer"]:checked').each(function(){
        if ($(this).val() == "monkPL"){
            secondaryResults.mnk += .96;

        }

        if ($(this).val() == "berserkerPL"){
            secondaryResults.ber += .97;

        }

        if ($(this).val() == "defenderPL"){
            secondaryResults.def += .98;

        }

        if ($(this).val() == "thiefPL"){
            secondaryResults.thf += .99;

        }

        if ($(this).val() == "magePL"){
            secondaryResults.mge += 1;

        }

        if ($(this).val() == "clericPL"){
            secondaryResults.cle += 1.01;

        }

        if ($(this).val() == "rangePL"){
            secondaryResults.rng += 1.02;

        }

        if ($(this).val() == "druidPL"){
            secondaryResults.dru += 1.03;

        }



        })



    });



$('#submit').on('click', function() {
$('input[name^= "answer"]:checked').each(function(){
        if ($(this).val() == "monkP"){
            primaryResults.mnk += 1.3;

        }

        if ($(this).val() == "berserkerPM"){
            primaryResults.ber += 1.26;

        }

        if ($(this).val() == "defenderPM"){
            primaryResults.def += 1.27;

        }

        if ($(this).val() == "thiefPM"){
            primaryResults.thf += 1.28;

        }

        if ($(this).val() == "magePM"){
            primaryResults.mge += 1.29;

        }

        if ($(this).val() == "clericPM"){
            primaryResults.cle += 1.31;

        }

        if ($(this).val() == "rangePM"){
            primaryResults.rng += 1.32;

        }

        if ($(this).val() == "druidPM"){
            primaryResults.dru += 1.33;

        }


        })


    });

$('#submit').on('click', function() {
$('input[name^= "answer"]:checked').each(function(){
        if ($(this).val() == "monkPH"){
            primaryResults.mnk += 1.46;

        }

        if ($(this).val() == "berserkerPH"){
            primaryResults.ber += 1.47;

        }

        if ($(this).val() == "defenderPH"){
            primaryResults.def += 1.48 ;

        }

        if ($(this).val() == "thiefPH"){
            secondaryResults.thf += 1.49;

        }

        if ($(this).val() == "magePH"){
            primaryResults.mge += 1.5;

        }

        if ($(this).val() == "clericPH"){
            primaryResults.cle += 1.51;

        }

        if ($(this).val() == "rangePH"){
            primaryResults.rng += 1.52;

        }

        if ($(this).val() == "druidPH"){
            primaryResults.dru += 1.536172;

        }



        $("#submit").css('display','none');
        })


    });



$('#submit').on('click',function(){

if (Object.keys(primary).every(function(key) {
return key == 'def' || primary.def > primary[key];
})) {
$(results.eq(0)).appendTo$("#display_box");
}
});

}); 




});
```

Comment: I bet ya all the programmers in here prefer to see the code ;)

Comment: Yes, there's a better way. Loop over `Object.keys(primary)`.

Comment: `Object.keys(primary).every(function(){})`

Comment: @yezzz added code = )

Comment: We don't need all that code, especially with so many unnecessary blank lines. Just show the part that's relevant to the question.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `Array.prototype.every` function to test every property in the object.

```js
var primary = {
  A: 100,
  B: 5,
  C: 6,
  D: 15,
  E: 30
};

if (Object.keys(primary).every(function(key) {
  return key == 'A' || primary.A > primary[key];
})) {
  console.log("Success!");
}
```

`Object.keys(primary)` returns an array containing all the property names in `primary`, i.e. `["A", "B", "C", ...]`.

`every()` then calls the function on every element of that array; it returns `true` if all the calls return `true`, otherwise it returns `false`.

The function then checks whether `primary.A` is greater than `primary[key]`, for each given key. Testing `key == 'A'` keeps it from trying to compare `primary.A` with itself, so it effectively ignores that property in the object.

Comment: I am a bit shaky on how your method works. (Im a pretty new coder) . 

Can you explain the logic to me? 

and did I do this correctly 

if (object.keys(primaryResults)).every(function(key)) {
  return key == 'def' || primaryResults.def > primaryResults[key];
 };

Comment: Uppercase `O` in `Object`.

Comment: I've added some more explanation to the answer.

Comment: Thanks Barmar, ive only been at this about 4 months, your answer was easy to understand... One last thing. I seem to be having a weird syntax issue. I even tried copy/pasteing your code right into my file.

Its giving me uncaught syntax token } , telling me my closing onload tag is unexpected

Updated the script in the post

Comment: You're missing the code to run when the test is successful. `if (some_condition) { stuff to do }`

Comment: Ok, changed that in the snippet, this is a sample of the "stuff to do" obviously I am going have to write out one for all the results... 
but that fixed the syntax error

But what I need it to do  is ask IF primaryResults.def is greater than all other properties of Primary results AND secondaryResults.def is greater then all other properties of secondaryResults 

then  

$(results.eq(0)).appendTo$("#display_box");

their are 16 variables for the test 

so there 8x8 = 64 results lol

Comment: There's no `$` at the end of `appendTo`.

Comment: You can use `&&` to combine multiple conditions in the `if`. I know you said you're a beginner, but you need to learn basic syntax like this.

Comment: You should probably write a function that does the object check, so you don't need to repeat the code for both primary and secondary results.

Comment: yeah, thanks so much, Im pretty much teaching myself from tutorials,books and people willing to help me. I thank you for your patience